# Setting width of layers panel in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.18, table-of-contents, panel

When I open QGIS, the Layers Panel defaults to a width that doesn't show the "Remove Layer/Group" button. So I have to resize the panel to show the button every time I open QGIS.

Is it possible to set a default width for this panel so I don't have to resize it?

I am using QGIS 2.18.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: I add another panel (in my case Advanced Digitizing Tool or Value Tool). Some of these panels try to keep their width. But I agree, would be nice if   a default width can be set.

Comment: It would be nice for the project to remember, but you don't need that button as the function is available via the layer-right-click popup menu, so there's no need to resize (i.e. it's exactly the same number of button clicks - one on the layer and one to remove).  If you still want to use the button, you still don't need to resize as you can click the >> button at the edge of the pane and any hidden buttons appear in a popup (this applies to all QGIS menus).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a bit of **Python**, we could create a *startup.py* script which sets the width of the layers panel by using the following:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget

for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget): 
    if x.objectName() == 'Layers':
        x.setFixedWidth(250)
        x.setMinimumWidth(100)
        x.setMaximumWidth(1000)
```

Save the script in your `/.qgis2/python/` directory. Now whenever you load QGIS, the width of the layers panel will be set accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Joseph this is a good solution. However I did find that setting a lower minimumWidth after the fixedWidth made the fixedWidth redundant. So for my purposes I only used x.setMinimumWidth(250), 250 was the magic number for me, this still allowed me to make the panel wider if needed.

Comment: @balex - Most welcome, glad it helped! Funny, when I remove `setFixedWidth`, it doesn't resize accordingly. Perhaps because I'm using 2.18.2 but atleast it works for you :)

Answer (score 9):

For reference: there is [Bug report #15479 Layers panel does not remember size](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15479) which is related to your issue.